# Conflicting functions using multiprocessing package

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I have a function executed in parallel using the multiprocessing package, while another one is executed in the main process. The parallel function runs until the main one is finished. Both of them work, but not together. Both functions only share one argument in common (a global variable), and both use the BeautifulSoup package. Also, the functions have internal local variables which have the same name, but I don't think this is a problem.

The declaration of the functions is:

```
    stop_event, output = mp.Event(), mp.Queue()
    count_price_change = mp.Process(target=count, args=(stop_event, output, data_2, header_2, driver, lancer))
    count_price_change.start()
    start = time.time()
    
    collected = create_array_features(data_1, header_1, prices, change, changepct, volume, lancer)
    #PROBLEM IS HERE, eventually with lancer ?? 
    stop = time.time()
    time.sleep(frequency_get - (stop - start))
    stop_event.set()
    counts_changes = output.get()
    count_price_change.join()
    count_price_change.terminate()
```

The exact error I get is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 80, in create_array_features
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 300, in __init__
    markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 240, in prepare_markup
    exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 374, in __init__
    for encoding in self.detector.encodings:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 265, in encodings
    self.markup, self.is_html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 323, in find_declared_encoding
    declared_encoding_match = xml_encoding_re.search(markup, endpos=xml_endpos)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I have tried minimum reproducible examples but they all work. I am unable to figure out why I get an error. The whole code is (start at the bottom):

```
def parse_html(names, driver):

    # need to make it wait until elements appear otherwise doesn't catch anything
    list_names = []
    for i in range(len(names)):
        html_name = names[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_name, "html.parser")
        match = soup.find('a').text
        list_names.append(match)

    lancer = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')
    prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-field.item-price')
    change = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-field.item-change.pn--color')
    changepct = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-field.item-changepct.pn--color')
    volume = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-field.item-volume.is-made')

    return list_names, lancer, prices, change, changepct, volume

def create_array_features(data, header, prices, change, changepct, volume, lancer):

    # create an array of features
    try:
        list_to_parse = data.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
    except:
        list_to_parse = data.get_level_values(0).unique() #this is for when the dataframe is empty

    features = []
    for i in range(len(list_to_parse)):
        # prices
        html = prices[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        soup = [text for text in soup.find_all(text=True) if text.parent.name != "label"][1]
        match = prq.check_unit(soup)
        features.append(match)
        #parse some other stuff...

    collected = pd.DataFrame([features], columns=header)
    collected['time'] = pd.to_datetime(lancer)
    collected = collected.set_index('time')

    return collected

def count(stop_event, output, data_2, header_2, driver, lancer):

    try:
        list_to_parse = data_2.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
    except:
        list_to_parse = data_2.get_level_values(0).unique() #this is for when the dataframe is empty

    change_count_prices = [0 for i in range(len(list_to_parse))]
    change_count_volume = [0 for i in range(len(list_to_parse))]
    last_prices = [None for i in range(len(list_to_parse))]
    last_volumes = [None for i in range(len(list_to_parse))]

    while not stop_event.is_set():

        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section.watchlist__container.expanded')))
        names_ = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-symbol-inner')

        _, _, prices, _, _, volume = parse_html(names_, driver) #each time must update the price in order to check if has changed

        for i in range(len(list_to_parse)):
            html = prices[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            soup = [text for text in soup.find_all(text=True) if text.parent.name != "label"][1]
            match = prq.check_unit(soup)
            if match != last_prices[i]:
                change_count_prices[i] =+ 1
            last_prices[i] = match

            #do some other stuff

    change_count_prices.extend(change_count_volume)
    print("exited and will stop")
    collected = pd.DataFrame([change_count_prices], columns=header_2)
    collected['time'] = pd.to_datetime(lancer)
    collected = collected.set_index('time')
    output.put(collected) #LIFO queue with ouput that comes at the end when event is set

def collect(data_1, data_2, header_1, header_2, frequency_get, driver,
            lancer, prices, change, changepct, volume):

    stop_event, output = mp.Event(), mp.Queue()
    count_price_change = mp.Process(target=count, args=(stop_event, output, data_2, header_2, driver, lancer))
    count_price_change.start()
    start = time.time()

    collected = create_array_features(data_1, header_1, prices, change, changepct, volume, lancer)
    stop = time.time()
    time.sleep(frequency_get - (stop - start))
    stop_event.set()
    counts_changes = output.get()
    count_price_change.join()
    count_price_change.terminate()
```

Comment: Why you think multiprocesseing is the problem ? You got a type error .Check your code outputs again

Comment: The type error is due to multiprocessing, because when parsing html the html is None or something like that, and this is uniquely due to multiprocessing. Proof is I don't get any error when I execute each function independently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to find the answer. The problem comes from the fact that, Selenium cannot handle multiple tabs in parallel, having the same driver. In order to use Selenium in multithreading, you must use one different driver per thread. Which is not was I was making above

Answer (score 0):

Because i cant recreate your problem , generally i will suggest not to use shared variables between processes ,except you know the state of each every time.Also you need always to have the 2 functions or scripts in the same directory , because many fork issues can show up like errors.

So generally you can solve issues like that by communicating between main and child processes like this with multyprocessing Pipe(),and share real-time the state of the variable:

```
parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
p = Process(target = plot_map_function,args =(self.variable1,self.variable2,child_conn))
p.daemon=True
p.start()
parent_conn.recv()
p.join()
```

in other function :

```
def plot_map_function(var1,var2,conn_to_parent):
    #do something with variables 
    conn_to_parent.send(variable_i_want_to_send)
    conn_to_parent.close()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but all this is already known. The state of lancer is known, it is only read, so it's not a problem